# Start process with args which contains a path with blanks

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I need to start a process from a powershell script and pass such params :
-a -s f1d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\file.iss
to do that, I write the folowing code :

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("$setupFilePath", '-a -s -f1"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"') 
$process.WaitForExit()
```

as a result the process starts but the last argument : -f1d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\file.iss
is not passing correctly. Help, please

Comment: Try use `Start-Process` cmdlet. 
`Start-Process -FilePath "yourPath" -ArgumentList "arg1 arg2"`

Comment: triyng but with no success. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 12):

I think you can use `Start-Process`:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $setupFilePath -ArgumentList '-a','-s','-f1"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"' |
    Wait-Process
```

Comment: The code above does not work in my case. It works only if a param '-f1"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"' contains a path with no blanks

Comment: Can you update your question with the error message you're getting?

Comment: actually there are no error message. I determine than it does not work as I want, because if launching $setupFilePath executable with incorrect path it works but in other way then expected. I also tried to pass a proper path(with no blanks) and it worked as I want

Comment: I am using powershell v1 if it has some influence

Comment: That could have something to do with it.  Try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to [figure out how `Start-Process` is sending the arguments](http://pshdo.com/archive/2013/3/18/monitoring-windows-process-start-and-exit-events.html) to `$setupFilePath`.  There maybe some kind argument pre-processing going on.

Answer (score 5):

I understand your question to be: 
*How to pass multiple arguments to start a process where one of the arguments has spaces?*

I'm assuming the equivalent in a Windows batch file would be something like:

```
"%setupFilePath%" -a -s -f1"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"
```

where the double quotes allow the receiving process (*setupFilePath* in this case) to receive three arguments:

1. `-a`
2. `-s`
3. `-f1"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"`

To accomplish this with the code snippet in your question I would use back ticks (*to the left of the 1 and below the escape key, not to be confused with a single quote; aka Grave-accent*) to escape the inner double quotes like this:

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("$setupFilePath", "-a -s -f1`"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss`"") 
$process.WaitForExit()
```

Note that in addition to using back ticks I also changed the single quotes around your argument list to double quotes.  This was necessary because single quotes do not allow the escapes we need here (http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html).

[Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17562145/3166133) should work just fine.  If it doesn't then I would guess that *setupFilePath* is not interpretting `-f1"d:\space here\file.ext"` as you expect it to.

**OPINION ALERT** The only thing I would add to his answer is to suggest using double quotes and back ticks in order to allow using a variable within the path for argument `-f1`:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $setupFilePath -ArgumentList '-a','-s',"-f1`"$pathToVCCS`"" |
Wait-Process
```

This way you won't have a hard-coded, absolute path in the middle of a long line.

Answer (score 2):

On PowerShell v3, this works:

```
& $setupFilePath -a -s -f1:"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"
```

Using the [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com) echoargs command shows this:

```
25> echoargs.exe -a -s -f1"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"
Arg 0 is <-a>
Arg 1 is <-s>
Arg 2 is <-f1d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss>

Command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  -a -s "-f1d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"
```

On V2 use - note the addition of a backtick on the last double quote:

```
PS> echoargs.exe -a -s -f1"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss`"
Arg 0 is <-a>
Arg 1 is <-s>
Arg 2 is <-f1d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss>

Command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  -a -s -f1"d:\some directory\with blanks in a path\fileVCCS.iss"
```

Comment: If you need it to work on 2.0, put a backtick ` before the last double quote.