# how to go through a loop and match a number of strings

Tags: powershell

I have the below that puts a number of registry keys into a kind of Array. I am trying to get my head around how do I look at each of these objects and decide that based on a specific string value of "en-US" or "de-DE", "it-IT" etc then find that string and execute a setup file.

A server could have a number of languages installed and I want to ensure it goes through each language and installs a setup - once that is done then go back and look at it again and run another setup for a language that has not been touched by the script.

---

UPDATE:

Thanks for the answers so far and I have got the below that works. BUT I need to be able to write-host stating something like "Running Italian setup" and also use Start-Process? I am trying to use Start-process but I get an error:

```
$ItalianSpellingHotfix = "C:\Temp\IE11_Spelling_Hyphenation\IE-Spelling-it.msu"
$langInstalled = Get-ChildItem -Path hklm:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages | Select -ExpandProperty PSChildName

switch ($langInstalled)
{
    {$_ -match "it-IT"} {start-process c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe $ItalianSpellingHotfix /quiet /norestart}
    #{$_ -match "de-DE"} {"Running German Setup"}
    #{$_ -match "en-US"} {"Running US English Setup"}
    #{$_ -match "es-ES"} {"Running Spanish Setup"}
}
```

ERROR:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/quiet'.
At line:9 char:26
+     {$_ -match "it-IT"} {start-process c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe $ItalianSpel ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: You need to loop over `$langInstalled` and should probably use a `switch` statement to check if it matches rather than `if..else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of what Arco was suggesting

```powershell
$langInstalled = Get-ChildItem -Path hklm:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages | Select -ExpandProperty PSChildName

$langInstalled | ForEach-Object{
    switch -Wildcard ($_){
        "*it-IT*"{Write-host "Language contains Italian - running that setup"}
        "*de-DE*"{Write-host "Language contains German - running that setup"}
        "*en-US*"{Write-host "Language contains German - running that setup"}
        default{Write-host "Language contains something else - running that setup"}

    }
}
```

You can see we are using [switch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847750.aspx) inside a loop. You needed the loop to react to *each* language.

FYI my code design was meant to be compact for better readability. You can whatever code you want in the switch block

```
"*it-IT*"{
    Write-host "Language contains Italian - running that setup"
    Start-Process c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe -ArgumentList "$ItalianSpellingHotfix /quiet /norestart"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I actually was in the middle of making this as acro444 said to use switch as well and did something similar to the above - but,  problem - how do I call a process from AND also write-host tp say which install I am doing? ie - I have done this: {$_ -match "it-IT"} {start-process c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe $ItalianSpellingHotfix /quiet /norestart} - but start-process is not working and I cannot see how I can also state "Starting Italian setup".............I will update the question with the new code and my query as well so you can see it better

Comment: @lara400 You are not using Start-Process correctly. Your arguments need to be sent as an array to `-ArgumentList`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550663/start-process-with-args-which-contains-a-path-with-blanks which has answers

Comment: yep, gotcha Matt - I also saw that post and your answer above is what I have done. Thanks a lot!

Comment: btw - do you know if powershell will wait for each install to finish and then run the next install - I will give it a try anyway but just wondering if you know.