# msi installation throwing 1639 as exit error code for msi having space between characters

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have some msi like  "A B C.msi"  , When i am trying to install it using powershell it is throwing exit code error as 1639.

When i rename the msi to "ABC.msi" without space , installation is getting good. How to get rid of space thing . I do not want to rename the msi . Please sugegst .

```
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i,<path>,/quiet -PassThru -Wait
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the path parameter is not correct.

Would you please try:

```
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i,'<path>',/quiet -PassThru -Wait
```

(or maybe try "")

See [Start process with args which contains a path with blanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550663/start-process-with-args-which-contains-a-path-with-blanks)

Edit 
Since previous method doesn't work, my last try would be:

```
$pathToMSI = "c:\downloads\a b c.msi"
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList '/i',"`"$pathToMSI`"","/quiet" -PassThru -Wait
```

Comment: I did both. Even i assigned the name to a variable and then tried to use.

Comment: Could you please share the path? And if you double click the msi file, will it install OK?    And as mentioned in the link, also try '"<path>"'

Comment: Yes. Double clicking is installing it . Even If i am renaming the file something without space it works. Path is like below.
C:\Downloads\"A B C.msi"

Comment: Would you please also try '"c:\downloads\a b c.msi"', "c:\downloads\a b c.msi" and 'c:\downloads\a b c.msi' ?

Comment: No Luck. Same issue.

Comment: My last try would be    $pathToMSI = "c:\downloads\a b c.msi"                                                                                   Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList '/i',"`"$pathToMSI`"","/quiet" -PassThru -Wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115513/discussion-between-rishua-and-shane-lu).